# Как правильно поменять props внутри компонента?

Tags: reactjs

В Каком методе жизненного цикла и как эффективнее менять props и делать setState внутри компонента, менять стейт на осве пропсов
componentWillReceiveProps или ComponenWillMount?

Answer (score 0):

Что значит эффективнее? Метод `сomponentWillMount` срабатывает до маунтинга компонента и выполняется при серверном рендеринге. State рекомендуется инициализировать в конструкторе вместо этого.

`componentWillReceiveProps` вызывается каждый раз когда в компонент пришли пропсы. Следовательно менять стейт логично в методе `componentWillReceiveProps`.